# How to resize yuv420sp using FFmpeg

Tags: java, android, c, ffmpeg

How to resize yuv420sp data into some other resolution.I tried using ffmpeg sws_scale but no success.I tried by converting yuv420sp to yuv420p and then tried to resize yuv420p into RGB24 via sws_scale but the things it works when both src and destination width and height are same, but for different resolution didn't get correct rgb24. Can anyboody guide me with example code using c or if possible through Java itself .The final resized data must be in yuv420p.
In my case i am trying to downsize the yuv420sp  for eg 640*480 to 320*240 or 176*144.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do what you're trying to would be

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -s 320x240 -pix_fmt yuv420p output_file
```

Does that not work for you?

Comment: Hi  thanks for the reply but I want to  achieve it progrmmatically using c or if possible in java

Comment: Sorry, I should've seen that.  Presumably the command line can be translated into C code using the FFmpeg API, but I don't know how off the top of my head.